# JavaScript Passing Parameters to modal ASP.NET Core

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with my modal boostrap seems like not passing parameter to modal. Here is my code:

My view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeId)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Fname)  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Lname)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhoneNumber)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Position)</td>
        <td>
            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.EmployeeId">Edit</a> |
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-emp-id="@item.EmployeeId"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="vertical-align:middle;margin-top: -5px"></span> Delete</button>
        </td>
    </tr>

}
```

My modal:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm Delete</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Are you sure you want to delete invoice number:</p>
            <input type="text" name="empID" value=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <form asp-controller="Employee" asp-action="Delete" method="post" class="form-inline" role="form">
                <input type="hidden" id="Id">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="vertical-align:middle;margin-top: -5px"></span> Delete</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My JavaScript:
I think the problem is somewhere in this code but I don't know why.

```
<script src="./javascript.js" type="text/javascript">
$("button[type='button']").click(function () {
    $("#myModal").find("input[type='text']").val($(this).attr("EmpID")); 
});
```

What makes it wrong with my work? Does anyone knows why is not passing the parameter to model?

I'm just a beginner and I have no idea whats going on in my codes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your button doesn't have an attribute named `EmpId`. However it does have an attribute named `data-emp-id` which I assume contains the value you want.

jQuery has a [data method](https://api.jquery.com/data/) for accessing data attributes easily; in short you can get it using `$(this).data("emp-id")`

Comment: @NightShade555 WELCOME TO SO. if this answer has helped you consider accepting and upvoting it. SO works in this way..this way this question will not attract spam answers.